# Como reduzir a quantidade de elif

Tags: python

Estou começando no python e no projeto atual (que é para fazer rateio de impressoras) tem uma grande quantidade de elif, tem algum método que eu possa reduzir isso no python? desde já eu agradeço.

Esse e o código atual:

```
 for i in range(len(list_nome_serial_valor)): 
        lista = list_nome_serial_valor[i][0]

        if "SAME" in lista:
            same = Setores("48","SAME")
            same.adicionar_impressora(list_nome_serial_valor[i])
            setores.append(same)

        elif "PORTARIA CENTRAL" in lista or "RECEPCAO MULTIPROFISSIONAL" in lista:
            rm = Setores("40","RECEPCAO MULTIPROFISSIONAL")
            rm.adicionar_impressora(list_nome_serial_valor[i])
            setores.append(rm)

        elif "CONTABILIDADE" in lista:
            contabilidade = Setores("27","CONTABILIDADE")
            contabilidade.adicionar_impressora(list_nome_serial_valor[i])
            setores.append(contabilidade)

  #[mais elif's ...]
```

**obs:** Ele separa o nome das impressoras e cria um objeto com todas impressoras do setor

Comment: Primeiro, fazer algo como `('A' or 'B') in X` não verifica se A ou B estão em X; na verdade primeiro será avaliado a expressão `'A' or 'B'`, que sempre retornará `'A'` e, assim, somente verificará se A está em X, ignorando B. Para verificar os dois precisa fazer `A in X or B in X`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acredito que muita coisa pode ser refatorada baseado no trecho de codigo que você forneceu, mas para a sua em especifico eu:

- criaria um dicionario codigo:regex
- iteraria na lista list_nome_serial_valor
- em cada iteração eu iteraria no dicionario usando items()
- executaria o re.search com o valor do items() e o nome
- caso o retorno for diferente de None (significa que deu match) eu executaria o codigo normal
- depois de executar voce da um break pra sair do inner loop

```python
#Supondo que list_nome_serial_valor seja do tipo [(a,b,c),(d,e,f)...]
import re

match_dict = {
    "48": "SAME",
    "40": "(RECEPCAO MULTIPROFISSIONAL|PORTARIA CENTRA)",
    "27": "CONTABILIDADE"
}

for nome, serial, valor in list_nome_serial_valor: #outer loop
    for k, v in match_dict.items(): #inner loop
        if re.search(v, nome) != None:
            set = Setores("48","SAME")
            set.adicionar_impressora((nome, serial, valor))
            setores.append(set)
            break
```

Eu escrevi esse código de cabeça então pode ter algum bug, mas se tiver algum problema é só deixar um comentário que eu atualizo/explico o código

Answer (score 1):

Eu tentaria mover o código que há em comum em todas as ramificações do `if` para fora dele (seja antes ou depois). Colocar todos esses `if`s em uma função a parte também ajuda.

```py
def criar_setor(lista):
    if "SAME" in lista: return Setores("48", "SAME")
    if "PORTARIA CENTRAL" in lista or "RECEPCAO MULTIPROFISSIONAL" in lista:
        return Setores("40", "RECEPCAO MULTIPROFISSIONAL")
    if "CONTABILIDADE" in lista: return Setores("27", "CONTABILIDADE")
    # Mais um monte de ifs aqui...
    raise ValueError("Não sei")

for i in range(len(list_nome_serial_valor)): 
    lista = list_nome_serial_valor[i][0]
    setor = criar_setor(lista)
    setor.adicionar_impressora(list_nome_serial_valor[i])
    setores.append(setor)
```